# Update field in one table based on select in another one

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 2 tables (products and cart). Cart is `foreign key` in products.

When I generate all codes for each product with the same foreign `key(id_cart)` I need to update the correspondent line in the table cart, but only if all products with the same `id_cart` already have this field fill.

I would like to do this with only one query. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It sounds like you might need a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, for instance something like this `update` with `having` clause:

```
update cart c set status = 'COMPLETE' 
  where exists (select 1 
                  from product p where p.id_cart = c.id
                  having count(1) = count(code))
```

or `merge` statement:

```
merge into cart c 
using (select id_cart 
         from product
         group by id_cart 
         having count(1) = count(code)) p
on (p.id_cart = c.id)
when matched then update set status = 'COMPLETE'
```

Test data:

```
create table product (id number(3), name varchar2(10), code varchar2(4), id_cart number(3));
insert into product values ( 1, 'pen',    'A',   1 );
insert into product values ( 2, 'pencil', 'X',   1 );
insert into product values ( 3, 'box',    null,  2 );
insert into product values ( 4, 'paper',  'Q',   2 );

create table cart (id number(3), status varchar2(10));
insert into cart values (1, null);
insert into cart values (2, null);
```

Result:

```
ID   STATUS
---  ----------
  1  COMPLETE
  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update-from
example

```
UPDATE  dbo.Cart
SET     [fieldToUpdate] = p.fieldToUpdate
FROM    dbo.Cart c
        JOIN dbo.products p ON c.fk = p.fk
WHERE   cart.id = c.id
```